# can't export class in plain JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

I am trying to `export` a `module` and `import` it another file, but for some reason I am getting `unexpcted token export` error. I am using the latest version of chrome `55.0.2883.87` , This syntax should be supported in `Chrome` correct?

I am using the latest version of `chrome` and plain `JS`.

```
class GanttChartService{
 ...
}
export default {GanttChartService}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the curly braces:

```
class GanttChartService{
 //...
}
export default GanttChartService;
```

You can also do it all in one:

```
export default class GanttChartService{
 //...
}
```

---

> I am using the latest version of chrome and plain JS.

That's also a problem. Currently, using `import` and `export` requires at least a bundler (Webpack, Browserify) if not a transpiler (Babel) in most environments. The only browser I'm aware of that has any `import`/`export` support as I write this in late January 2017 is the Safari Technology Preview. You can track Chrome's support in [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1569), [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=594639), and in detail in [this design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vjiWxwhg9D0GNNOYgw3AxMG0iKOC9I3jlID4GTgZsac/edit).

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense: Then something *else* is going on. The above are both correct exports. I've added a note at the end, in case you weren't aware that support for `import`/`export` is currently very, very thin on the ground.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on that. I will accept your answer as soon as it let's me.